# Hibernate detach retains eager children causing OutOfMemory error in large queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We use a JPA criteria query to load all entities in a certain type for processing. The relevant code is like:

```
Stream<T> getQueryResultStream() {
  EntityManager entityManager = ...;
  TypedQuery query = entityManager.createQuery(...);
  return query.stream().map(entityManager:detach);
}
```

The entity being loaded has two child entities, both are `OneToMany` collections, with `Cascade.All` and `Fetch.EAGER`. When we run the query over a large data set the host runs out of memory.

While debugging we noticed that, in the `StatefulPersistenceContext` class, the detach call fails to remove the two child entities from the `nonLazyCollections` field.

Apparently the Fetch.EAGER annotations are causing the problem. We need to keep them eager, and the only workaround we can think of is to replace detach() with a call to EntityManager.clear().

Are there better workarounds for this problem?

Also, we also use the same query code to load and detach entities and then write them back with merge. Would switching to clear() affect this pattern in some non-obvious ways?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14735 for this, let's continue the discussion there.